# Is there a way to create a telegram bot that looks for a defined text in my conversations, groups and channels?

Tags: search, notifications, telegram, telegram-bot

Sorry for my English, I'd really like to know if there's a way to create a telegram bot that automatically makes local research in my conversations, groups and channels looking for a particular text, for example once a day, and if it finds at least one result I receive a notification. I hope it's clear what's the problem for me. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the client robot to check your specific words or sentences, which means the robot that is mounted on your account and can check.

If you want a robot to check your messages, you have a problem because the robot has to see wherever you are a member, which is not the case.

That"s why you have to use the client robot
There are different languages ​​for writing such robots

My suggestion is the Telethon module in Python that you can see its documents from **[Here](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/)**. Also, **[Here](https://t.me/TelethonChat)** is the Telegram group of this module that you can use.

But if you want to do it in another language, you can look for it as a **client robot** or **cli bot**

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I didn't know about these client robots, I'll try immediately, thanks!